# Sending Input Value to JQuery Function

Tags: jquery, ajax, input

Currently a theme I purchased is set up with a star rating system. From what I've been able to come up with, a JQuery function calculates the rating based on the ID of the star that is clicked, as controlled by this code below:

```
<div class="rating-send-form">
<div class="rating-ipnuts">
<div class="rating-details">
<button class="send-rating"><?php _e('Post Wait Time','ait'); ?></button>

<div class="rating clearfix" data-rating-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-rated-value="0">

<div class="stars clearfix">
<?php for($j = 1; $j <= $starsCount; $j++) { ?>
<div class="star" data-star-id="<?php echo $j; ?>"></div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
</div>
```

The data-star-id that is clicked is sent to calculate the rating, like below:

```
// rating
$(document).on("click", "#ait-rating-system .rating-send-form .star", function(event) {
var rating = $(this).parent().parent();
var ratingId = rating.data('rating-id');
var id = parseInt($(this).data('star-id'));
$(this).parent().find('> div').slice(0,id).css("background","url('"+themeUrl+"/design/img/rating_star_active.png') no-repeat 0 0");
rating.data('rated-value',id).addClass('already');      
});
```

What I'd like to do is replace the clicking of stars with a simple text input field. How would I go about sending a text value to this function to replace the data-star-id that is currently sent?

Comment: `replace the clicking of stars with a simple text input field` so the of value input should be sent when we click on input fields ?? geting confused

Comment: sorry for the confusion. rather than having users select a rating of 1-5 stars, I would like them to physically enter 1,2,3,4 or 5 in a text box, and have that as the value that is sent to calculate the new rating.

Comment: then i guess you need to replace the `div` with single input...no need of loop there ($j)... and `keyup()` event instead of click for that input and get the value with `$("#inputid").val()`...and where is the code for post,ajax or something which sents the data to server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first create the textfield and bind an event to it let's say the blur event. On blur, you should change the rating as follows:

```
$('#textfield1').on("blur",function(event) {
var rating = $('#ratingdiv');// you should give your div an id to be able to target it 
rating.data('rated-value',$(this).val());      
});
```

I hope I was able to get your point

Comment: How can I achieve this while still using the current on("click") function. I edited the HTML code above to include the button used etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, you could take the value of the input with .val()